# Regex: Delete "new line" command and replace with whole next line

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I am new here and also to *regular expressions*. I have the following problem and I cannot figure out, why it doesn't work: There are, for instance, 4 lines, all of them end with a "new line" command. Like this (or please look at picture for more detail):

```
1 "1" "Sentence 1" \n
2 "2" "sentence 2 part 1: \n
3 Sentence 2 part 2"\n
4 "3" "Sentence 3" \n
```

What I want to do is, to delete the "new line" in line 2, or in other words: pull line number 3 and merge it with line 2. (I hope someone understands this). At the end it look like this:

```
1 "1" "Sentence 1"\n
2 "2" "sentence 2 part 1: Sentence 2 part 2"\n
4 "3" "Sentence 3"
```

I tried out this regex, but it didn't work. The idea was to find a new line command followed by a " character. I use the replace feature in the atom-Editor with the following code:

```
\n(?=[^"])
```

Even it is marked correctly, meaning the selection works, it was not possible to delete/replace the line. What is the problem with it? Is it even possible within "atom"?

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can try doing this in emacs? It seems like Atom doesn't support multiline search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Atom find / replace functionality is tricky to some extent. It should follow JS engine but lacks features in different aspects of an imperfect implementation of syntax. You may work around it using a regex like this:

```
^(.*\s+.*)\s+([\s\S]+)
             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Replace with:

```
$1$2
```

Comment: hey revo thanks for your answer. unfortunately, it doesn't work with atom. maybe I used it wrong (copied and pasted it)?

Comment: It works with the latest version. Re-check your input. See if there is a hidden character in between or not. @mark85